# Counting field total against another table column value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
room      | beds available | ****table room****
==================================
room1     | 4
room2     | 2 
room3     | 4

room      | occupant       | ****table occupant****
==================================
room1     | arnold
room1     | berry
room2     | charles
room2     | daisy
room3     | eric
room3     | frank
room3     | greg
```

I looking to get the following output:

No. of rooms with beds available: 2 || Rooms with beds available: room 1, room 3

i reckon i need to

1. store count* for each unique room and store the count as an array
2. subtract beds available for each room against this array
3. display the room name when there's a result > 0

How should the php snippet code look like?

Comment: Just before I answer, let me just clarify: are you looking to calculate the available beds by subtracting the number of occupants from the "occupant" table from the number in the "room" table?

Comment: Hi James, I'm not actually looking to calculate available beds. For that i used sum(beds available) - count * from occupant.

I'm looking to 1. count the rooms with beds available, and 2. display the rooms name out

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These SQL queries will do the trick.

Remember, you can remove unwanted columns to save the amount of data you're processing...

```
select r.id AS 'room',
    r.beds as 'total_beds',
    count(o.occupant) as 'taken_beds',
    r.beds-count(o.occupant) as 'free_beds'

FROM room r LEFT JOIN occupant o ON r.id = o.room
GROUP BY r.id

HAVING r.beds > count(o.occupant)
```

This will only return the rooms that are not full.

[image: MySQL Result]

If at any other point, you wish to return full rooms too, simply remove the "HAVING" clause

```
select r.id AS 'room',
    r.beds as 'total_beds',
    count(o.occupant) as 'taken_beds',
    r.beds-count(o.occupant) as 'free_beds'

FROM room r LEFT JOIN occupant o ON r.id = o.room
GROUP BY r.id
```

[image: MySQL Result without HAVING clause]

Comment: Hi James, is it possible to count the numbers of rows of result seperately?

Rooms that are not full: 2

Comment: if the room is not taken at all, it does not show up in this query. i.e. if room 2 free beds = 2, it will only show room 1 and room3. How can i show all 3?

Comment: Good catch, Spencer!

These rooms are currently excluded as the JOIN expects something in both tables. If you update this to a "LEFT JOIN", this then includes the additional rooms. I verified this by adding room 4 with no occupants. Works just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this all can be done with a simple SQL query that should look something like this:

```
SELECT room.beds AS beds, COUNT(occupant.occupant) AS beds_occupied
FROM room
LEFT JOIN occupant ON occupant.room = room.room
GROUP BY room
HAVING (beds - beds_occupied) > 0;
```

You can use the 'HAVING' clause which is similar to the WHERE clause but works with aggregates. I haven't run this exact query on your exact tables so there might be a typo, however, I hope the idea what the query is supposed to do is clear.

Answer (score 0):

So something like this where you can change how many available beds you need..

```
SELECT r.*, COUNT(*) AS occupied, r.beds - COUNT(*) AS rest
FROM room r
LEFT JOIN occupant o ON r.room = o.room
GROUP BY r.room
HAVING r.beds - occupied >= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL offers `GROUP_CONCAT` to aggregate strings:

```
select 
  count(*) as number_of_rooms, 
  group_concat(room) as rooms
from room r
where beds_available >
(
  select count(*)
  from occupant o
  where o.room = r.room
);
```

This selects rooms with more beds available than occupied and then aggregates the resulting rows to one row containing the number of available rooms and a string with the room names comma-separated.